# CSV file formatting doesn't work for GCP BlobWriter

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have same data as list of dict and want to import these in a CSV file in a GCP bucket.

I'm importing these object as streaming:

```
blob = defaults.bucket.blob(filename)
csv_writer = BlobWriter(blob, content_type="text/csv")

for data in result.get('events'):
    _source = data.get('_source', {})
    csv_writer.write(json.dumps(_source, indent=2).encode('utf-8'))
```

where `_source` is dict.

The actual result in the CSV file is JSON formatting, not CSV.

For example:

```
{           
  'key':'value'     
}{          
  'key':'value'         
}{
```

Comment: `json.dumps()` seems to be the cause... Just to be clear, setting the content type alone won't magically change the metaformat of the data written. You need to format the data as CSV explicitly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import csv

blob = defaults.bucket.blob(filename)
csv_writer = BlobWriter(blob, content_type="text/csv")

# Assuming '_source' is a dictionary and result.get('events') is a list of dictionaries
field_names = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']  # Replace with actual keys in your '_source' dictionaries

# Write CSV header
csv_writer.write(','.join(field_names).encode('utf-8') + b'\n')

for data in result.get('events'):
    _source = data.get('_source', {})
    
    # Convert each dictionary to a CSV row
    csv_row = [str(_source.get(key, '')) for key in field_names]
    
    # Write CSV row to the file
    csv_writer.write(','.join(csv_row).encode('utf-8') + b'\n')
```

Comment: Code-only answers are impopular here. Please [edit] to explain what you changed and why.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).